# Closures: Line by Line explanation of "Javascript: Good Parts" example?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, closures

I'm reading "Javascript: The Good Parts" and am totally baffled by what's really going on here. A more detailed and/or simplified explanation would be greatly appreciated.

```
// BAD EXAMPLE

// Make a function that assigns event handler functions to an array  of nodes the wrong way.
// When you click on a node, an alert box is supposed to display the ordinal of the node.
// But it always displays the number of nodes instead.

var add_the_handlers = function (nodes) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i += 1) {
        nodes[i].onclick = function (e) {
            alert(i);
        }
    }
};

// END BAD EXAMPLE
```

The `add_the_handlers` function was intended to give each handler a unique number (i). It fails because the handler functions are bound to the variable `i`, not the value of the variable `i` at the time the function was made:

```
// BETTER EXAMPLE

// Make a function that assigns event handler functions to an array of nodes the right way.
// When you click on a node, an alert box will display the ordinal of the node.

var add_the_handlers = function (nodes) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i += 1) {
        nodes[i].onclick = function (i) {
            return function (e) {
                alert(i);
            };
        }(i);
    }
};
```

Now, instead of assigning a function to onclick, we define a function and immediately invoke it, passing in `i`. That function will return an event handler function that is bound to the value of `i` that was passed in, not to the `i` defined in `add_the_handlers`. That returned function is assigned to onclick.

Comment: See the questions tagged in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+closures+loops

Comment: You can also play around with a live demo http://jsbin.com/sezisalulede/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think this is a very common source of confusion for newcomers to JavaScript. First I would suggest checking out the following Mozilla Dev article for brief introduction on the topic of closures and lexical scoping:

- [Mozilla Dev Center: Working with Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures)

Let's start with the bad one:

```
var add_the_handlers = function (nodes) {
// Variable i is declared in the local scope of the add_the_handlers() 
// function. 
   var i;

// Nothing special here. A normal for loop.
   for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i += 1) {

// Now we are going to assign an anonymous function to the onclick property.
       nodes[i].onclick = function (e) {

// The problem here is that this anonymous function has become a closure. It 
// will be sharing the same local variable environment as the add_the_handlers()
// function. Therefore when the callback is called, the i variable will contain 
// the last value it had when add_the_handlers() last returned. 
           alert(i);
       }
   }

// The for loop ends, and i === nodes.length. The add_the_handlers() maintains
// the value of i even after it returns. This is why when the callback
// function is invoked, it will always alert the value of nodes.length.
};
```

We can tackle this problem with more closures, as Crockford suggested in the "good example". A closure is a special kind of object that combines two things: a function, and the environment in which that function was created. In JavaScript, the environment of the closure consists of any local variables that were in-scope at the time that the closure was created:

```
 // Now we are creating an anonymous closure that creates its own local 
 // environment. I renamed the parameter variable x to make it more clear.
 nodes[i].onclick = function (x) {

     // Variable x will be initialized when this function is called.

     // Return the event callback function.
     return function (e) {
         // We use the local variable from the closure environment, and not the 
         // one held in the scope of the outer function add_the_handlers().
         alert(x);
     };
 }(i); // We invoke the function immediately to initialize its internal 
       // environment that will be captured in the closure, and to receive
       // the callback function which we need to assign to the onclick.
```

Rather than having the callbacks all sharing a single environment, the closure function creates a new environment for each one. We could also have used a function factory to create a closure, as in the following example:

```
function makeOnClickCallback (x) {
   return function (e) {
      alert(x);
   };
}

for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i += 1) {
   nodes[i].onclick = makeOnClickCallback(i);
}
```

Comment: One somewhat related question. What does "e" mean in function(e), and could it be replaced with any var? I used to think it meant event, but now I'm confused.

Comment: @Matrym: Yes, should be an argument which the browser passes to the callback function when the onclick event is raised. Check out [this quirksmode article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html) on how this is handled in different browsers.

Comment: What happens if we don't use a variable? Do we pass so we can chain stuff?

Comment: @Matrym: You mean for "e" parameter? Unless you need to access the event object, you don't need that parameter. You could even not define it: `return function () { alert(x); };`

Comment: what about a fiddle for the live demo of the GOOD example http://jsbin.com/qoyuvecucuju/1/edit?js,output and one for the BETTER example http://jsbin.com/setaxegehote/1/edit?js,output

Comment: Nothing like a line by line detailed explanation, my doubts are gone.
+100 if I could

Answer (score 3):

It's all about closures. In the first example, "i" will be equal to "nodes.length" for every click event handler, because it uses "i" from the loop which creates the event handlers. By the time the event handler is called, the loop will have ended, so "i" will be equal to "nodes.length".

In the second example, "i" is a parameter (so a local variable). The event handlers will use the value of the local variable "i" (the parameter).

Answer (score 2):

In both examples any node that's passed has an onclick event handler bound to it (just like `<img src="..." onclick="myhandler()"/>`, which is bad practice after all).

The difference is that in the bad example every closure (the event handler functions, that is) is referencing the exact same `i` variable due to their common parent scope.

The good example makes use of an anonymous function that gets executed right away. This anonymous function references the exact same `i` variable as in the bad example BUT since it is executed and provided with `i` as its first parameter, `i`'s value is assigned to a local variable called ... eh? ... `i`, exactely - thus overwriting the one defined in the parent's scope.

Let's rewrite the good example to make it all clear:

```
var add_the_handlers = function (nodes) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i += 1) {
        nodes[i].onclick = function (newvar) {
            return function (e) {
                alert(nevar);
            };
        }(i);
    }
};
```

Here we replaced `i` in the returned event handler function with `newvar` and it still works, because `newvar` is just what you'd expect - a new variable inherited from the anonymous function's scope.

Good luck figuring it out.

Comment: typo in "alert(nevar)". It should be "alert(newvar)"

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with closure.

When you do the thing in the bad example,

when you click each node, you will get the latest i value (i.e. you have 3 nodes, no matter what node you click you will get 2). since your alert(i) is bound to a reference of variable i and not the value of i at the moment it was bound in the event handler.

Doing it the better example way, you bound it to what i as at the moment that it was iterated on, so clicking on node 1 will give you 0, node 2 will give you 1 and node 3 will give you 2.

basically, you are evaluating what i is immediately when it is called at the line }(i) and it got passed to parameter e which now hold the value of what i is at that moment in time.

Btw... I think there is a typo there in the better example part... it should be alert(e) instead of alert(i).