# javascript 'curry', need some explanations on this code

Tags: javascript

I am reading the book "JavaScript-The Good Parts", in chapter 4.14 Curry, the book gives the following example:

```
Function.method('curry', function(){
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice,
        args = slice.apply(arguments), //1st-arguments
        that=this;

    return function(){
       return that.apply(null, args.concat(slice.apply(arguments))); //2nd-arguments
    }
})

var add1=add.curry(1);
document.writeln(add1(6)); // 7
```

I have two questions on this code:

1. There are two places using '**arguments**'. In the method invoking in the last two lines code, is it so that '**1**' goes to the 1st-arguments and '**6**' goes to the 2nd-arguments?
2. There is a line of code `apply(null, args.concat(slice.apply(arguments)))`, why does it `apply(null,...)` here?, what is the sense to apply a argument to a null object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> There are two places using 'arguments'. In the method invoking in the last two lines code, is it so that '1' goes to the 1st-arguments and '6' goes to the 2nd-arguments?

Yes, 1 is part of `arguments` of the outer function, while 6 goes the `arguments` in the inner function. The inner function can capture all other variables in a closure except for `arguments` and `this`, which have a special meaning inside a function, hence are not part of that closure. So `that`, and `args` are captured, but not `arguments`.

> There is a line of code apply(null, args.concat(slice.apply(arguments))), why does it apply(null,...) here?, what is the sense to apply a argument to a null object?

Invoking a method with a null context will simply set the `this` value to the global object. In the case it seems the author does not care what that context is.

Answer (score 2):

That example was kind of tricky for me too, because I'm not experienced in JavaScript, so I will try to explain it as I would have wished to be explained to me. Due to that reason it might be too explicit!

Also, before you start, I would recommend you to review the 'closure' part (for me to understand closure, was very helpful this quote):

"A closure is a special kind of object that combines two things: a function, and the environment in which that function was created. The environment consists of any local variables that were in-scope at the time that the closure was created." (from Mozilla developer network) - [Closures: Line by Line explanation of "Javascript: Good Parts" example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947749/line-by-line-explanation-of-javascript-good-parts-example)

And now about the curry example:

apply(this, arguments) - this method can be applied to a function to  call it and sends the 'this' variable and the parameters variables as an array (arguments).

For example:

```
// JSON objects
var ob1 = { // first object
    a : 0,
    b : 0
};

var ob2 = { // the second one
    a : 0,
    b : 0
};

// a function that updates 'a' and 'b'
function update(newA, newB) {
    this.a = newA;
    this.b = newB;
}

// 'this' is equal with ob1 and arguments array is [10, 20]
update.apply(ob1, [10, 20]);

// the same as above, but 'this' is here ob2
update.apply(ob2, [30, 40]);

/* after update:
ob1 {
      a: 10,
      b: 20
    }
ob2 {
      a: 30,
      b: 40
    }
*/
```

Now, that you have understood apply, you might ask why is in this example is called only with a single parameter.

```
  args = slice.apply(arguments);
```

The function 'slice' takes an array and some parameters that represent indexes and forms a new array only with those.For example:

```
var anArray = ['red', 'green', 'black'];
var otherArray = anArray.slice(0); // after this line 'otherArray' will be ['red']
otherArray = anArray.slice(1,2); // 'otherArray' will be ['green','black'] 
// but what happens id you don't specify any indexes?
otherArray = anArray.slice();
// otherArray will be equal with ['red', 'green', 'black'], the same as 'anArray'
// it just makes a copy of it
```

So, when it does:

```
args = slice.apply(arguments)
```

is the same as:

```
args = slice.apply(/*this*/ arguments, /*arguments*/ undefined);
```

which is it 'almost' like saying:

```
args = arguments.slice(); // args will have all the elements the same as arguments
```

The reason why it does that is because args will be an array with all the methods of an array, but 'arguments' doesn't have any methods.

**"Because of a design error, arguments is not really an array. It is an array-like object. Arguments has a length property, but it lacks all of the array methods." (from the book)**

Let's recap, we need it these two lines:

```
   var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
   args = slice.apply(arguments);
```

just to make 'arguments' to have all the methods that are specific to the an array.
In our case we will need the 'concat' method that takes two array and joins them.

```
Function.method('curry', function(){
       var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
       args = slice.apply(arguments);
       that=this; // saves this (which will be a function)

       return function(){
    // 'that' will be the same as this from above
    // and is a function that we call it with the apply
          return that.apply(/*this*/null, /*arguments*/ args.concat(slice.apply(arguments))); 
   // 'this' was null, an arguments was a join between 'args' and 'arguments'
}
});
```

Finally, you just have to understand how will be used:

```
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

var add1 = add.curry(1); // add is function, and 'add.curry(1)' returns a function
    // that will have 'a' set as 1(one) and 'b' as undefined(not being set)

var sum = add1(6); // 7
// when you call add1(6), you actually call that function that was returned by
// the line add.curry(1), with 'b' equal with 6
```