# Crockford's deentityify method - p.41 of The Good Parts

Tags: javascript, function, module

In a fit of self-improvement, I'm reading (and rereading) TGP by Señor Crockford. I cannot, however, understand the middlemost part of his deentityify method.

```
...
return this.replace(...,
    function (a, b) {
       var r = ...
    }
);
```

I think I understand that:

1. this.replace is passed two arguments, the regex as the search value and the function to generate the replacement value;
2. the b is used to access the properties in the entity object;
3. the return `? r : a;` bit determines whether to return the text as is or the value of the appropriate property in entity.

What I don't get at all is how the a & b are provided as arguments into `function (a, b)`. What is calling this function? (I know the whole thing is self-executing, but that doesn't really clear it up for me. I guess I'm asking how is this function being called?)

If someone was interested in giving a blow by blow analysis akin to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947749/line-by-line-explanation-of-javascript-good-parts-example), I'd really appreciate it, and I suspect others might too.

Here's the code for convenience:

```
String.method('deentityify', function ( ) {
    var entity = {
        quot: '"',
        lt: '<',
        gt: '>'
    };

    return function () {
        return this.replace(
            /&([^&;]+);/g,
            function (a, b) {
                var r = entity[b];
                return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a;
            }
        );
    };
}());
```

Comment: The nutshell version: replace() itself calls the function passed to it. Consider it a "callback" function, a very typical pattern.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yep, I can see this now. What I don't get is why b is used to check whether the matched text is a property in entity, but a is returned if r !== 'string' (i.e., entity[b] is not found, I think). I would have expected (1) check if b is a property in entity,  (2a) if so, substitute the value of b (i.e., r) or else (2b) stick b back into the string. If a is the numerical offset, why is it returned as the replacement value?

Comment: Don't have the book in front of me, so can't help you there.

Comment: I updated the post with the code - a bit rude of me to expect someone else to :)

Comment: See my "answer", which is more of a comment. phihag slightly misspoke, neither `a` nor `b` are numerical offsets.

Comment: Yes, Dave, and then I misapplied phihag's analysis by saying `a` was was the numerical offset when he said it was `b`. (I knew `b` wasn't, and since he was saying one of the two was, I didn't look carefully). I'd started to twig that `b` had to lack the surrounding `&` and `;` to match the entity property. Thanks for the help to you both. I'm not really sure which answer to tick because @phihag's isn't quite right, but it's the fuller answer. Perhaps you can update it, phihag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a` isn't the numerical offset, it's the [matched substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

`b` (in this case) is the first grouping, i.e., the match minus the surrounding `&` and `;`.

The method checks to make sure the entity exists, and that it's a string. If it is, that's the replacement value, otherwise it's replaced by the original value, minus the `&` and `;`

Answer (score 5):

The [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function can take a function as the second parameter.

This function is then called for every match, with a signature that depends on the number of groups in the regular expression being searched for. If the regexp does not contain any capturing groups, `a` will be the matched substring, `b` the numerical offset in the whole string. For more details, refer to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).