# Module - JavaScript: Good Parts. How is this callback getting its arguments?

Tags: javascript

I am engaging with the famous "JavaScript: The Good Parts" by Douglas Crockford. It is an awesome book of course. While, I may not have been ready for it yet, i thought of giving it a shot. I need some help to understand the following example. The second argument in the `replace()` takes 2 arguments `a` and `b`. But where are they defined? How do they take a value? Thanks in advance. I did refer to another [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570990/crockfords-deentityify-method-p-41-of-the-good-parts), but i don't think it really helped.

```
String.method('deentityify', function ( ) {

// The entity table. It maps entity names to
// characters.

var entity = {
quot: '"',
lt: '<',
gt: '>'
};

// Return the deentityify method.

return function ( ) {

// This is the deentityify method. It calls the string
// replace method, looking for substrings that start
// with '&' and end with ';'. If the characters in
// between are in the entity table, then replace the
// entity with the character from the table.

return this.replace(/&([^&;]+);/g,
function (a, b) {
var r = entity[b];
return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a;
    }
   );
  };
}( ));
```

Comment: indentation gore..

Comment: When you don't know how a function works, a good idea is to look it up in a documentation. For JavaScript the best one is the MDN: [replace, with a function as parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

Comment: It is called in `String.replace` which is an existing String method.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's answered by any documentation on the topic

Comment: Thanks @DenysSéguret, I of course looked at MDN document prior to trouble this community. But the document suggests that the functions argument takes `match, p1, p2 ... p3, offset, string` so many parameters. How does it work?

Comment: When declaring a function with less parameters, it just means that the other provided arguments will be ignored. Here the code only needs two of them.

Comment: Cool, @DenysSéguret. Thanks. it somehow did not occur to me. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions can be written to accept other functions as arguments. Such functions are called [Higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function). In this example `a` and `b` are just names for parameters of the function. What exactly will be assigned to that parameters is up-to the implementation of the `replace`.

A good illustration of this idea would be

```js
var items = [{name:"item1",price:100}, {name:"item2",price:200}];

// lets find an object in the array, that has name "item2"
var result = items.find(function(a){return a.name==="item2"});
console.log(result);
```

in this code function `find` accepts a function that determines a match-criteria. Code of function `find` will iterate the array and apply match-criteria function to each element until either an array ends or first match is found. For better understanding you can change parameter function like:

```
result = items.find(function(whatever){return whatever.price>=100});
result = items.find(function(whatever){return whatever.price>100});
```